# Building an uberjar with Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, uberjar

I want to build an uberjar (AKA fatjar) that includes all the transitive dependencies of the project. What lines do I need to add to `build.gradle`?

This is what I currently have:

```
task uberjar(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Foobar',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to try using the [application plug-in](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) instead.

Comment: This will work as long as you do not have any dependencies. But once your project has dependencies those won't get bundled into the uberjar.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

<s>Have you tried the fatjar example in the [gradle cookbook](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook#Cookbook-Creatingafatjar)?</s>

What you're looking for is [the shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) for gradle

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. It helped. Though I hit another issue which was solved by a bit of googling. I'll add another answer expanding on that.

Comment: It looks like the cookbook now requires a login. As this is exactly what I am looking for, could you paste the recipe in here please?

Comment: @tarzan three years later, and I'd now use the shadow plugin https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow

Comment: this is very simple and worked the first time (after trying many other "answers": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738676/how-to-specify-main-class-when-using-fatjar-plugin-in-gradle-build

Comment: Things change in 3 years. And I'd still use the shadow plugin ;-)

Comment: shadowjar isn't very well-maintained. See https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/476 and other critical issues that have gone unfixed for months.

Answer (score 42):

I replaced the `task uberjar(..` with the following:

```
jar {
    from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Foobar',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

The exclusions are needed because in their absence you will hit [this](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/signing_a_custom_gradle_plugin_thats_downloaded_by_the_build_system_from_github) issue.

Comment: I think it should use `configurations.runtime` to include all runtime dependencies

Comment: i needed to add `with jar` below manifest to get the files in `java/main/resources` in the uberjar

Comment: That worked for me! Without the exclude part it was killing me with SecurityException and with this fix it works!

Comment: Best to even use the `sourceSets.getByName('main').runtimeClasspath`

Comment: anybody know what this would look like in kotlin (for the build.gradle,kts file) ?

Answer (score 8):

Simply add this to your java module's build.gradle.

mainClassName = "my.main.Class"

```
jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
  }  

  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

This will result in [module_name]/build/libs/[module_name].jar file.

Comment: but what is that code? What does configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } do?

Comment: @SamRedway `configurations.compile.collect` collects stuff from `compile`

The ternary lets it pull in both folders and zip-files (like jars) as if they were also folders

Comment: I haven't tried the other versions posted here, but this one works nicely and is nice and simple.

Comment: This answer excludes any `runtime` or `runtimeOnly` declared dependencies, which will cause the application to break at runtime.

Comment: @mkobit You can replace `compile` with `runtimeClasspath` as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278063/how-do-i-create-an-executable-fat-jar-with-gradle-with-implementation-dependenci/49284432#49284432).

Answer (score 5):

I found this [project](https://github.com/bond-/gradle-groovy-jar-example/blob/master/build.gradle) very useful. Using it as a reference, my Gradle uberjar task would be

```
task uberjar(type: Jar, dependsOn: [':compileJava', ':processResources']) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from configurations.runtime.asFileTree.files.collect { zipTree(it) }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'SomeClass'
    }
}
```

Comment: i get `Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes` when i try this

Comment: you need         `exclude "META-INF/*.SF"`
        `exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"`
        `exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"` like missingfaktor's answer

Comment: Does not seem to work with Gradle 5.3.1: "Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput."

Comment: it gives me java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException