# How to build fat jars with gradle 1.6

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have multiple projects using gradle. Each one of them generates a separate jar on build. I would like to make multiple fat jars which contains a subset of all the jars? I looked at other answers but they seem really old and hence does not seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986244/building-a-uberjar-with-gradle) to see how to build an "uberjar." Or at the very least use it as a model for your own uberjar task.