# How To Specify main class when using fatjar plugin in gradle.build

Tags: jar, build, gradle, intellij-13, uberjar

I am interested in building a single jar containing all the module dependencies and external jars in a single executable jar file which I will be able to run with `java -jar myApp.jar`.

I have module A which is dependent on module B.
Currently I'm using gradle, and my `build.gradle`script looks like this:

```
    apply plugin: 'fatjar'
    description = "A_Project"
    dependencies {
      compile project(':B_Project')
      compile "com.someExternalDependency::3.0"
    }
```

When I build it through gradle command: `clean build fatjar` a fat jar 'A.jar' is created as expected.
But running it with as I written above results in:
`no main manifest attribute, in A.jar`
How can I modify my `build.gradle` file and specify the main class, or the manifest?

Comment: No idea how to help You. It seems that command `clean build fatjar` has different outputs. Is that true?

Comment: See "Customization of MANIFEST.MF" in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have figured it out myself:
I've used uberjar Gradle task.
now my build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName  = 'com.organization.project.package.mainClassName'

version = '1.0'

task uberjar(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}} {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
}

manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.organization.project.package.mainClassName'
    }
}


dependencies {
compile project(':B_Project')
compile "com.someExternalDependency::3.0"
}
```

and now I i use it with the command:

> clean build uberjar

and it builds one nice runnable jar :)

Comment: i needed to add `with jar` below manifest to get the files in `java/main/resources` in the uberjar. Also inside collect is should be { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }...

Answer (score 5):

To get it working using fatjar, I added a manifest section in fatJar task:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation-Version': version
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.organization.project.package.mainClassName'
    }
}
```