# Gradle: Add jar & dependencies to exporting jar

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Assuming my gradle dependencies are :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

How can I add them in a jar file which is being created with `java` plugin and `:jar` task?

I only found [this](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_add_jars_into_a_jar) solution for the libs but didn't work either.

See that I have both local dependencies and maven dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jar {
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Comment: I can see the jars inside but they cannot be read (`NoClassDefFoundError`). Probably something wrong with my classpath, I investigate

Comment: the problem is probably, that you need the unzipped jars in the jar.   have a look at this stov thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986244/building-a-uberjar-with-gradle