# Gradle fatjar from directory

Tags: java, gradle, fatjar

I have a folder (`$buildDir/some/lib`) that has a lot of jars inside. I want to create a jar that has all of those jars inside but unzipped. I've tried numerous things but all of them failed including the one below:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'someTask') {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'some.Main'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from ("$buildDir/some/lib") {
        eachFile { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)  } }

    with jar
}
```

In this case the error is:

> Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: file
>   '/path/to/the/buidDir/above/someJar.jar'.

Any help?

EDIT:
I changed it to this but it still doesn't work.. jars are copied but they aren't unpacked.. help! why is this so hard?

```
task fatJar(....) {
    manifest {
        .....
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    FileCollection collection = files("$buildDir/some/lib")
    from collection.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }

    with jar
}
```

Comment: maybe similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986244/building-a-uberjar-with-gradle ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'some.Main'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    project.fileTree("$buildDir/some/lib").forEach { jarFile ->
        from zipTree(jarFile )
    }
    with jar
}
```

**Note**

In your first solution you get error *"Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI..."* because in the `eachFile` closure (see [CopySpec.eachFile()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#eachFile-groovy.lang.Closure-) you manipulate `FileCopyDetails` objects, while `zipTree` method expects a *Zip Path*. One solution would be to use `getPath()` method:  `eachFile { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it.getPath())  } }`